# How to add popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I want a popup when I click on button for every list.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));

    function displaySortedData() {
        var sortedJsonData = jsonData.sort(function (a, b) {
            return parseFloat(a.copay.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, "")) - parseFloat(b.copay.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, ""));
        });

        $('#externalPharmacyList').empty();

        sortedJsonData.forEach(function (item, index) {
            var fullAddress = item.address1 + " " + item.address2 + " " + item.city + " " + item.state + " " + item.zipCode;

            var listItemHtml = `
                                <li>
                                    <div class="b-m-pharmacy-det">
                                        <div class="b-p-name">
                                            ${item.pharmacyName}
                                            <small>${fullAddress}</small>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="b-m-qty">
                                            ${item.quantity} ${item.drugName}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="b-m-price" style="text-align:right">
                                            ${item.copay}
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" style="margin-left:25px">Use BidRx Card</button>
                                   </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6"> <img src="~/frontassets/images/BidRx-Discount-Card.jpg" /></div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                                                    <span style="font-weight: 600; font-size:13px; display: block; padding: 25px 20px 0px 20px;">Get your own BidRx "Prescription Savings Card" sent direct to your mobile. Show card to any of the pharmacies listed below to get instant savings.</span>

                                                <div id="divSlickTextCard" class="text-center p-25 ">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block">
                                                                    <input type="text" id="txtSlickTextName" placeholder="Enter Your Name" class="form-control" style="width:250px; display:inline-block" />
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block">
                                                                   <input type="text" id="txtSlickTextEmail" placeholder="Enter your Mobile Number" class="form-control" style="width:250px;display:inline-block" />
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <a id="btnSendCard" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send my Card!</a>
                                                                    <button type="submit" id="btnSendCard" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send my Card!</button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>
                                </li>`;

              $(listItemHtml).hide().appendTo('#externalPharmacyList').delay(index * 300).fadeIn(500);  
        });
    }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $('.b-m-pharmacy-det button').on('click', function () {
                // Get the corresponding card section
                var cardSection = $(this).closest('.b-m-pharmacy-det').next('.collapse');

                // Toggle the visibility of the card section
                cardSection.collapse('toggle');
            });
        });
```

I am fetching json data then populating it. I am adding card which I want want through popup but it is not happening. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I understand things correctly. It seems like the issue with your code is related to the way you're binding the click event to the buttons. Since the buttons are dynamically added to the DOM after the page loads, the click event handler you've set up in `$(document).ready()` won't recognize these new elements.

To fix this, you should use event delegation. This means binding the event to a static parent element (which is present when the page loads) and specifying that it should only react to events that bubble up from specific child elements (in your case, the buttons). The `$(document)` object is a common choice for the parent element, but it's more efficient to choose a closer static parent if possible.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // ... your existing code ...

    // Event delegation for dynamically added buttons
    $('#externalPharmacyList').on('click', '.btn-primary', function () {
        // Get the corresponding card section
        var cardSection = $(this).closest('.b-m-pharmacy-det').next('.collapse');

        // Toggle the visibility of the card section
        cardSection.collapse('toggle');
    });
});
```

In this revised code, the click event is bound to #externalPharmacyList, which is assumed to be a static parent element. The event will only be triggered when a child element matching the selector `.btn-primary` is clicked. This way, even buttons added to the DOM after the initial page load will have the correct event handler applied to them.

Comment: Thanks Sarthak for reply. It's working for me